# UWP app is not passing certification process

Tags: c#, c++, boost, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am having problems with passing through certification process when I try to submit an update to UWP app. In the certification report it says:

API ?generic_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ in boost_system.uwp.dll is not supported for this application type. BlenderCycles.dll calls this API.

API ?system_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ in boost_system.uwp.dll is not supported for this application type. BlenderCycles.dll calls this API.

The issue is very confusing, because BlenderCycles.dll has used boost library before and the code did not changed. Any ideas what could be the problem?

I use boost library from [here](https://github.com/wpbest/Boost), which is specifically for Windows 10 UWP apps.

**Edit**
: I forgot to mention that at one point I had to recompile boost library, because visual studio started throwing errors about boost_system.uwp.dll because it was compiled by an older compiler. That is when this problem started.

Comment: If just checking the report, I could only know that BlenderCycles.dll calls some APIs from boost_system.uwp.dll, but these APIs are not supported in UWP. You could change to 'Release' mode and start it from Visual studio to see if you will get some exception message.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT I tried that, but that's the problem, that it works in Debug and Release modes, while it fails to pass the certification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was solved by adding BOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED definition to BlenderCycles library.